# help with t-sql data aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Based on the following table

```
Area  S1 S2 S3 S4 
--------------------
A1    5  10 20 0
A2    11 19 15 20
A3    0  0  0  20
```

I want to generate an output that will give the number of columns not having "0".

So the output would be

```
Area  S1 S2 S3 S4   Count 
-------------------------
A1    5  10 20 0    3
A2    11 19 15 20   4
A3    0  0  0  20   1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way would be to add the result of case statements together:

```
select area, s1, s2, s3, s4,
    case when S1 <> 0 then 1 else 0 end +
    case when S2 <> 0 then 1 else 0 end +
    case when S3 <> 0 then 1 else 0 end +
    case when S4 <> 0 then 1 else 0 end as Count
from YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to get you thinking, you could also do this with a join:

```
SELECT t1.*, COUNT(t2.Area) AS Count
FROM Table t1
LEFT JOIN Table t2
ON t2.Area = t1.Area AND (t2.S1 <> 0 OR t2.S2 <> 0 OR t2.S3 <> 0 OR t2.S4 <> 0)
GROUP BY Area
ORDER BY Area
```